# Lebesgue integrable discontinuity points

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

If a function is Lebesgue integrable, is it possible that it has as set of discontinuity points measure bigger than zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The set of discontinuity points can even be the whole space. For instance, $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is Lebesgue integrable, with its integral being $m(\mathbb{Q})=0$.

Comment: $1_\mathbb{Q}$ has all measure $0$ points?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is discontinuous at every point (because any interval contains both a rational and an irrational number), and its integral is $m(\mathbb{Q})$ which is $0$. You can see the last statement by covering $\mathbb{Q}$ by intervals $I_n = (q_n - \varepsilon/2^n,q_n+\varepsilon/2^n)$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: but then the set of discontinuity points do not have a measure bigger than zero or am I wrong?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören No, the set of discontinuity points is the whole space. An interval around an irrational number still has a rational number in it, so $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is discontinuous at every irrational number as well. Note that $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a very pathological function, because it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of functions each of which have only finitely many discontinuities (each is discontinuous at a finite set of rational numbers), but the limit is discontinuous at every point.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Another way to see it. Fix $x$. Passing along rational sequences converging to $x$ the limit is $1$, but passing along irrational sequences the limit is zero. These don't agree, so $f$ is not continuous at $x$.